# Select 1000 samples per group from a table in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-athena

I have a table with the below schema in AWS Athena
[image]

Number of unique standard_lab_parameter_name, units pair in DB is ~3k
& the DB has about 80 Million entries. Now, I wish to get 1000 samples(random) per unique standard_lab_parameter_name, units pair hence nearly 3k x 1000 rows. I tried searching the internet for any such query but in vain.  Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CTE to generate random row numbers for each `standard_lab_parameter_name`, `units` pair, and then select the first 1000 rows for each pair by requiring the row number to be `<= 1000`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY standard_lab_parameter_name, units ORDER BY RANDOM()) AS rn
    FROM yourtable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn <= 1000
```